# How can I use the on_message_edit event to block swear words? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to delete the message if someone edits the message into a swear word message using the `on_message_edit` event, but I've been trying to figure this out and nothing has worked so far. Here is the code that doesn't work.

```
with open("badwords.txt") as file:
    blacklist = file.read().split('\n')

@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after, message):
    for word in blacklist:
        regex_match_true = re.compile(fr"[{symbols}]*".join(list(word)), re.IGNORECASE)
        regex_match_none = re.compile(fr"([{letters}]+{word})|({word}[{letters}]+)", re.IGNORECASE)
        if regex_match_true.search(message.content) and regex_match_none.search(message.content) is None:
            #embed here
            await message.delete()
            break
```

Comment: Can you please share how you defined `blacklist`?

Comment: Yes, give me a sec

Comment: Here it is: `blacklist = file.read().split('\n')`

Comment: Have you also defined which file you want to read? Do not see that in the code and maybe should be added.

Comment: Yes I have. I can post that if you want.

Comment: Someone please help me

Comment: Please do include this code, as well as any errors or traceback that may be helpful.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_message_edit` event has no `message` argument. There are arguments `before` and `after`, both of which are `discord.Message` object. As far as I understand, after a message is edited, you are trying to delete it if it contains a blacklist word. You can get the content of the edited message using `after.content`. You can then check if it contains the word blacklist.

```py
blacklist = open('badwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    for word in blacklist:
        if word in after.content:
            await after.delete()
            return
```

This is a simple example of how you you can do this, but if you want to use `regex`, you can use it too.

## Reference

- [`on_message_edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("badwords.txt") as file:
    blacklist = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    for word in after.content.split():
        if word.lower() in blacklist:
            #embed here
            return await message.delete()
```